# SQLite.Net-PCL CreateTableAsync add column

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I am using the SQLite.Net-PCL library to manage the SQLite database in my UWP app. The documentation says that calling CreateTableAsync is able to add columns to the table if a properly is added to the data model. However, when I add a property, the application throws an exception that says the table does not have a column named . This means that the new column was not created automatically. I am calling CreateTableAsync in the constructor of the class that manages database calls for the table with a repository design pattern.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the help center. Also add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the exception you are getting. So that people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled out all of my CreateTableAsync calls from the repository class constructors and moved them into separate Init Tasks so I can properly await. Now I can add columns to any table without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed decorations `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` for your class model. Please check the following DataTemple class.

```
public class DataTemple
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }     //primary key

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

For more detail you could also refer this [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/Sqlite/blob/master/Sqlite/Models/Person.cs#L12).

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I already have a PrimaryKey for all tables, but I used Guid instead of AutoIncrement. I changed to AutoIncrement int and it still didn't work. The initial table creation works fine but adding a column fails.

Comment: There may be a conflict between the multiple calls to CreateTableAsync. The first table I create is able to add columns. The tables created after the first have problems adding columns. I will look into creating tables sequentially and perhaps locking the database while in use.